# I am searching for a word to describe the area of a glacial valley where the sides transition into the floor?

Tags: geology, glaciology, geomorphology

I have been tasked with proof reading before publication a Russian paper that has been translated into basic English and am searching for a word to describe the area of a glacial valley where the valley sides transitions into the valley floor?

Answer (score 1):

Others may know if there is specific term for what you are asking. In case there isn't the following may help.

The walls of a valley are slopes - some are steeply dipping while others are shallow dipping. The top of a slope, whether natural or engineered, is called the crest of the slope and the bottom of a slope, where it meets the floor is called the toe of the slope.

Where the toe is not sharply defined and the slope transitions into the floor I would call that a transition toe.

The other term than is sometime used, instead of toe, in reference to continental slopes is foot.